# Powering an MCU from a front-panel header without ground

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply

I'm considering turning the ventilation units in our apartment "smart" by addition of a WiFi-capable MCU (ESP32C, RPi Pico W, ... - tbd). The units have a front panel with some status LEDs, a push button, and a photoresistor (for automatic dimming of the LEDs at night), connected through a 6-pin IDC connector, which I've already reversed:

[image: front panel schematic]

As you can see, there's no obvious signal ground, the cathodes of the status LEDs are probably pulled to ground by an MCU inside the unit itself.

For turning these things smart, I was thinking of designing an interposer board between the original front panel and the ribbon cable coming from the unit itself. However, I'd like to avoid needing an extra power supply, so I'm wondering if it would be possible to power the MCU from the connector somehow (I'll also have to see if that 5V rail can deliver enough current, obviously).

My thought was to add a diode + (super) cap tapping off across the push button (normally open, seems to short to ground), to have a poor man's UPS for the MCU for when the button is pressed (maybe followed by a DC/DC converter, although that would depend on the choice of MCU, the RPi Nano has one on board). Does that sound feasible at all or am I on the wrong track?

[image: MCU power supply]

My main experience is in software engineering.

Comment: If you draw too much current through that circuit, the unit will think that the button is being pushed. Is at least one LED always on? If so, I would consider using diodes to tap the power there -- but of course, you'd be limited to to the forward voltage of the LED itself.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered that. The LEDs go from all off to all on as the unit cycles through the speed settings, so unfortunately not.

Comment: So what are your actual constraints here? Is it completely out of the question to run a ground wire alongside the existing cable?

Comment: If it can be avoided, yes. The ribbon cable is hardwired to the original control unit, which also houses the mains AC connection (plus I'd prefer to not modify the original circuit). If it's infeasible to do from just the front panel connector, I'll probably just scrap the project, since it's not that critical.

Comment: "push button (normally open, seems to short to ground)" If +5V is not a pull-up, and it most likely isn't, then the button cannot possibly "short to ground". This doesn't mean you cannot skim some power of it. But you need better circuit examination. Most likely your circuit will have to operate with floating ground relative to the unit.